# Ef Code first Index with navigation property without adding Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I have a EF Code first class called UserTag.

UserTag has the following two properties

```
public string TagText { get; set; }
public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
```

Now I want an index that makes it so that a TagText is unique within a UserGroup. But the same TagText should be able to exist within two different UserGroups.

I have two problems, one is that TagText cannot be varchar(max) which it becomes and the second is that I don't have a UserGroupId to connect the Index to.

I would like to use Fluent API but could consider changing the Up and Down of my migrations.

But I would like not to have to add the UserGroupId and annotations over the TagText. Is this possible?

Best would be Fluent API but editing migrations would be okay too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I've missread your problem, I'll leave my original answer at the bottom (I have overread, that you do not want to add a ForeignKey property to your model).

### **Edited Answer:**

This is doable using the fluent API.

Basically you have to configure EF how to **map the navigation property** (UserGroup) to the database (the name of the Foreign key column, which does not exist in your model) and placing an **Index Attribute/Annotation** on it.

In order to solve the problem with the TagText column length (which by default is **nvarchar(max)** and thus cannot be part of an index (too long, you'll get an SQL Exception)), you also can use the fluent API and use **.HasMaxLength(StringLengthThatMakesSense)**. This also can be done by placing annotations in your model (see my old answer below).

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.UserGroup)
    .WithMany()  // I assume a 1 : many relation
    .Map(x =>
        // map the Foreignkey to the default naming convention
        x.MapKey("UserGroup_Id")  
        // add a Columnanotation, which you would place on the FK property, if you had one...
       .HasColumnAnnotation("UserGroup_Id", "Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 2)
        {
             IsUnique = true
        })));

  modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
      .Property(x => x.TagText)
      // configure the length of the column in the database
      .HasMaxLength(128)
      // add the Unique index information - I used this column to be the first in the index
     .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 1)
      {
          IsUnique = true
      }));
```

This should give you a migration that looks something like this:

```
     CreateTable(
        "dbo.UserTags",
         c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                TagText = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                UserGroup_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
             })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.UserGroups", t => t.UserGroup_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => new { t.TagText, t.UserGroup_Id }, unique: true, name: "UI_UserGroupTagtext");

     CreateTable(
        "dbo.UserGroups",
         c => new
         {
             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
          })
         .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

---

### Old Answer:

There are multiple solutions to your problem.

As you already mention, you always could do this in your database migration and just create the unique index using both columns (I guess the relational model contains the UserGroupId).

In order to create a unique index via **data annotations**, you would need to extend your model like so (which **requires EF 6.1**):

```
  public class UserTag {

    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required]
    [Index("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string TagText { get; set; }

    [Index("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }

    public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
  }
```

I **exposed the ForeignKey Property** (information: I am not 100% sure if this is required, maybe it also works when putting it on the navigationproperty directly). This works by conventions (by naming the FK property as the navigationproeprty with the Id Suffix. I assume the Id of a Usergroup is an integer). You can read more about this conventions on msdn (see the link at the bottom of the answer)

I also added a **StringLength** attribute, because otherwise EF would usually create an **NVARCHAR(MAX)** column, which will not work in SQL Server, since it exceeds the max. index length (as you already mentioned in your answer). This will also make EF validate the property's length when calling SaveChanges, without going to the database (but this can be disabled).

An other option is to do this via the **Fluent Api**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>
    .Property(t => t.TagText )
    .HasMaxLength(128)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 2);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>
    .Property(t => t.UserGroupId)
    .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("UI_UserGroupTagtext", 1);
```

In this example I also added the MaxLength inforatmation for the TagText (and a required information, since this seems to make sense at least for me...).

You can read more about EF and index [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti)